# React Native app Netinfo returns as unknown

Tags: react-native

I am building an app using react native but it's not fetching data using  axios only in ios, Android its working fine

When i checked the status of network using Netinfo it is returning unknown

```
 componentWillMount() {


    this.getLocation().done();


    var cusineServiceParams = {
      'limit': '6',
      'offset': '0',
    };
    axios.post('http://www.some.preview.domain.com/api/gc', cusineServiceParams)
      .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({
          cusineList: response.data
        })
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert('connection error');
      });

  }
```

I am always getting connection error

Here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>SOMEAPP</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.reactjs.native.example.somea</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>SomeApp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Andale Mono.ttf</string>
        <string>Arial Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Arial.ttf</string>
        <string>Comic Sans MS.ttf</string>
        <string>Courier New.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Georgia.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Microsoft Sans Serif.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-BlackItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-LightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>Rubik-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>SF-UI-Text-Regular.otf</string>
        <string>SanFrancisco.ttf</string>
        <string>SanFranciscoBold.ttf</string>
        <string>SanFranciscoThin.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Skia.ttf</string>
        <string>Times New Roman.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>rubicon-icon-font.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps for checking internet connection:

1. put this in import "NetInfo"
2. add this line in componentwillMount()

   ```
   NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);

     NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
       (isConnected) => { this.setState({ netStatus: isConnected }); }
     );

     NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => {

     if (isConnected)
     {
       //Put your code here when internet is connected
     }else{
      // Alert for no internet
     }
    });

   componentDidMount()
        {
          NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);

          NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
            (isConnected) => { this.setState({ netStatus: isConnected }); }
          );
        }
      //method
      handleConnectionChange = (isConnected) => {
              this.setState({ netStatus: isConnected });
              console.log(`is connected: ${this.state.netStatus}`);
            }
   ```

Comment: thanks but I have already checked the status of the internet, its coming unknown,the app is not getting connected to internet ,, also there is no issue in android ,, only in ios its ,, i am updating my info.plist also here

Comment: yea but the same problem was raised with me but with this code, I have solved it

Comment: i have done this ,, but its always going to the else condition of isconnected

Comment: I have fixed it by adding only NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.handleConnectionChange);
Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine for me as I just wanted to do something on app startup if a user had a network connection, very useful!